# ¿Cómo resolver el error Cannot decode byte '\xfa': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream" en Pandoc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pandoc

Estoy intentando obtener el contenido HTML de un sitio web en concreto mediante Pandoc, con el comando siguiente:

```
pandoc -s -r html https://hjg.com.ar/catena/c757.html -o c757.html
```

Yo he usado ese mismo comando en otros sitios webs obteniendo sin problema el contenido en un archivo local. Pero en este caso concreto no funciona, estoy teniendo el error:

> pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xfa':
> Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream

También he intentado usar `iconv` como sugiere la [documentación](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#character-encoding), con algo así:

```
iconv -t utf-8 | pandoc -s -r html https://hjg.com.ar/catena/c757.html -o c757.html | iconv -f utf-8
```

Y, viendo que esa página web está codificada en `iso-8859-1` intento algo así:

```
iconv -t iso-8859-1 | pandoc -s -r html https://hjg.com.ar/catena/c757.html -o c757.html | iconv -f utf-8
```

En ningún caso me funciona, obtengo siempre el mismo error.

#### Entorno

- SO: Ubuntu 18.04
- Pandoc: 1.19.2.4

Usando Pandoc desde la terminal

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es `pandoc` el que no reconoce el caracter `\xfa` (ú) y no hay posibilidad de realizar la conversión. Estuve buscando las opciones disponibles, pero `pandoc` puede trabajar solo desde la entrada estándar (stdin) o un archivo (local o remoto), por lo que se me ocurre que primero tienes que descargar el archivo con [wget](https://www.hostinger.mx/tutoriales/usar-comando-wget/), codificarlo con `iconv` y, si es necesaria alguna conversión, entonces sí usar `pandoc`.

```
# Descargar archivo y guardar, -O mayúscula para guardar
wget -O c757.html https://hjg.com.ar/catena/c757.html
# Codificar, especificando codificación de origen y guardando en otro archivo
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 c757.html -o c757-utf.html
# ¿Necesitas convertir a otro formato?
# Ya puedes usar pandoc sobre el archivo local
```

Después de probar en la terminal desde CentOs 7.9 (no debería haber diferencia con Ubuntu):

- Especificar la opción `-O` (con mayúscula) para guardar el archivo en un solo paso
- `iconv` funciona correctamente cuando se especifica la codificación original `-f ISO-8859-1` y se guarda en otro archivo `-o nombre-archivo`

Después de descargar y convertir prueba los comandos `file c757.html` y `file c757-utf.html`:

> c757.html: HTML document, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
> c757-utf.html: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. El archivo se carga con `wget` pero en dos tiempos, no sé por qué: primero me crea un archivo `.html` con el resultado de la ejecución del comando: `Resolviendo ... Conectado ... OK, etc` y luego me crea un archivo `c757.html.1` con el contenido. ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que se creen dos archivos? Luego, el archivo trae el carácter inspector `�` en lugar de los acentos, supongo que por el mismo problema de la codificación y al intentar `iconv` me da el siguiente error: *`secuencia de entrada ilegal en la posición 2014`*

Comment: @A.Cedano, actualicé la respuesta con base en pruebas reales.